# Proof that propositional logic remains consistent after the addition of a single axiom

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was wondering if someone might be able to supply a hint for the following exercise:

Let $\mathcal{P}'$ be the system obtained from $\mathcal{P}$ by adding the single wff $[p \to q]$ to the axioms of $\mathcal{P}$. Show that $\mathcal{P}'$ is consistent.

The axiom schemes of $\mathcal{P}$ are

$[[A \lor A] \to A]$

$[A \to [B \lor A]]$

$[[A \to B] \to [[C \lor A] \to [B \lor C]]]$

Modus Ponens is the only primitive rule of inference.

I have been unsuccessfully trying to prove that a contradiction can not be a theorem of $\mathcal{P}'$.

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  The definition of consistent says: "A set H of wffs is consistent iff there is wff **A** such that not H $\vdash$ **A**."  In other words, a set of wffs H is consistent if there exists some wff A, such that H cannot suffice to derive A.   If [p→q]. then by substitution [[p→q]→r] is a theorem.  So, by detachment, 'r' is a theorem; an entirely arbitrary variable.  Thus, every wff is a theorem and there is no wff **A** such that  not H $\vdash$ **A**.  For any wff **A**, H $\vdash$ **A**, where H is the new axiom set.

Comment: Does it matter that $[p \to q]$ is an axiom, not an axiom scheme? Therefore I believe that you can't substitute into it to get $[[p \to q] \to r]$?

Comment: That's an interesting question.  First off, if [p$\rightarrow$q] is an axiom, but not an axiom schema, then P has no axioms, it only has axiom schema.  So, the problem would propose adding that axiom to the existing axiom schema.  Second, it looks like evaluating [p→q] as a tautology or not still works the same way according to Mauro's reference. But, it's not a tautology.

Comment: Thinking more on it, the rule of substitution is valid for both axioms and axiom schema.  So, if the rule of substitution would have to get explicitly disallowed for a particular axiom such as [p→q], but still come as valid for an axiom like [[[p∨p]→p]→[q→[[p∨p]→p]]] .  That wouldn't just alter the axioms/axiom schema, but it would also alter the (derivable) rules of inference.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I think the idea is that $\mathcal{P}$ has all the axioms generated by the axiom schemes listed in the question. $\mathcal{P}'$ has all those axioms, plus one more; the single wff $[p \to q]$.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I'm not certain that the rule of substitution is valid for single axioms. Is it?

Comment: Usually, the rule of substitution is valid for single axioms.  Usually, a single axiom is a substitution of an axiom schema, and a tautology.  Thus, any substitution of that axiom is also obtained from the axiom schema without use of the axiom by substitution, and is a tautology also.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I don't think that this is the usual case. Here we are just given $[p \to q]$ as a single standalone axiom.

Comment: An axiom, usually, is an instance of an axiom schema.  Since axiom schema are usually tautologies, and the rule of substitution preserves truth, axioms are usually tautologies.  Since the rule of substitution preserves truth, substitution instances of axioms are also usually tautologies.  If you think that's wrong, then the rule of substitution would have to be invalid.  But, then there would have to exist some axiom such that it is a tautology, and a substitution instance of that axiom is not a tautology.  By all means, produce such an axiom and it's substitution instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref to : Peter Andrews, [An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=UaPuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA35), page 35.

Assueme that $\mathcal P' = \mathcal P \cup \{ p \to q \}$ is *inconsistent*.

By definition, this means that $\mathcal P'$ proves every formula.

Thus, also : $\mathcal P' \vdash \lnot (p \to q)$ and, by **Deduction Theorem** [see **1116**, page 30] :

> $\mathcal P \vdash (p \to q) \to \lnot (p \to q)$.

But we have that $(p \to q) \to \lnot (p \to q)$ is not a *tautology* [check with the truth assignment $\varphi : \text {Var} \to \{ \text T, \text F \}$ such that : $\varphi(p)= \text F$ and $\varphi(q)= \text T$].

Thus, we have a contradiction with the **Soundness Theorem** for $\mathcal P$ [see **1200**]: Every theorem of $\mathcal P$ is a tautology.

Comment: This doesn't work.   As soon as you add  [p→q], the Soundness Theorem  fails.  Thus, there is no contradiction of the Soundness Theorem, because, again, it's not a theorem.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood His proof says that it is a contradiction with the Soundness Theorem for $\mathcal{P}$, not $\mathcal{P'}$. The Soundness Theorem for $\mathcal{P}$ still holds right?

Comment: @user695931 Each axiom in P is a tautology, and the rules of inference are valid, so yes, the Soundness Theorem for P still holds.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood So I believe your first comment does not hold?

Comment: @user695931 My first comment says that when you add [p→q] to the system, the Soundness Theorem fails.  So, my first comment works.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I'm saying that the Soundness Theorem does not fail for what Mauro is using it for, which is $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Therefore the contradiction does exist.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - The assumprion of *inconsistency* of $\mathcal P'$ give us a derivation : $\mathcal P, p \to q \vdash ¬(p \to q)$. This one **is** a derivation in $\mathcal P$. Thus, we can use all the meta-results regarding $\mathcal P$ : Deduction Th, Soundness, etc.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No, it didn't give you such a derivation.  P⊢((p→q)→¬(p→q)) is not correct.  You can't start from the axioms of P and derive  ((p→q)→¬(p→q))   P is sound.  But, if p is false, and q is true, then ((p→q)→¬(p→q)) is true.  P′⊢¬(p→q).  Therefore, by the deduction theorem you could infer that: P'⊢(p→q)→¬(p→q).  But, that's P' assumed, not P.

Answer (score -1):

It suffices to show that there is a model of $\mathcal P$ where $p\to q$ is true.

As $\mathcal P$ is consistent, let $M$ be a model of $\mathcal P$. If $M$ says that $q$ is true or that $p$ is false, we are done. Otherwise (i.e., if it says $q$ is false and $p$ is true), swap $p$ and $q$, i.e., let $M'$ be such that it's truth value for a wff is the truth value $M$ assigns to the same wff wit $p,q$ exchanged. Then $M'$ is still a model of $\mathcal P$, and here $p\to q$ is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The text that this is from has not introduced models yet. Is there another approach?

Comment: This doesn't work either.  Every single wff is provable if [p→q] is an axiom.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Please check my comment under the question.